# Network capture using ethtool points to problem?

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

Issuing this:

```
ethtool -S <network device> |  egrep "err|fail"
```

I get the following errors:

```
tx_lost_interrupt: 225 
rx_alloc_fail: 36297
```

What is, **tx_lost_interrupt** and **rx_alloc_fail** ?

Do these errors indicate a real network problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are NIC- or driver-specific extended statistics, so it would be important to know the type of the network interface used and/or the name of the driver module used with it.

However, at least in kernel version 4.14.85, it looks like the string `tx_lost_interrupt` appears only in the Intel i40e NIC driver. [This seems to be the patch that originally added that statistic to the driver.](https://lists.osuosl.org/pipermail/intel-wired-lan/Week-of-Mon-20160111/003779.html)

It looks like it counts the times a software workaround was applied to a case of a lost hardware interrupt. I could not find any further description, but it looks like a workaround for a NIC hardware bug to me...

---

`rx_alloc_fail`, on the other hand, looks like it indicates the number of times the driver failed to allocate a memory buffer for received packet(s). That might indicate that your system is under some amount of memory pressure, and could use more RAM.